# object arrays are currently not supported

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem in Anaconda Spyder (Python)

This my script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

mydataset=pd.read_csv('wall_positions.csv')

x1=mydataset.iloc[:,6].values
x2=mydataset.iloc[:,7].values
y1=mydataset.iloc[:,8].values
y2=mydataset.iloc[:,9].values
z1=mydataset.iloc[:,10].values
z2=0.005
x_c= -mydataset.iloc[:,6].values + mydataset.iloc[:,7].values
y_c= -mydataset.iloc[:,8].values + mydataset.iloc[:,9].values
z_c=mydataset.iloc[:,10].values + 0.005
vol_c=x_c*y_c*z_c
```

error is x_c= -mydataset.iloc[:,6].values + mydataset.iloc[:,7].values

TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

What exactly is the issue

wall_positions.csv file is the following

[image]

Comment: check the dtype of the elements, perhaps it is str.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pd.read\_csv gives me str but need float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478070/pd-read-csv-gives-me-str-but-need-float)

Comment: add 'wall_positions.csv' to the question please.